# How to update the dropdown if I changed the data in ts file - angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently using angular2. I have a dropdown like

CFC Filter
                    
                        
                            {{val}}

in ts file I have declared 
this.filters = ["0", "60", "100", "180", "600", "1000"];

if I get this filter value from DB as 1000 how set that value in the dropdown whenever data is fetched from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set model variable which you use  inside the component as,

```
this.channelPropertyModel.channelFilter = "1000";
```

make sure you declared the variable too,

```
channelPropertyModel.channelFilter:string;
```

Comment: This does not seem working. I am doing a back end method call to get the data from DB and whatever filter value is in data fetched from DB, that value I should set in dropdown.

Comment: So, basically when ever a back end method called to get data then the drop down should get updated with the new data.

Comment: you should set channelPropertyModel.channelFilter = "1000"